# Adding eventListener for file drop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning how to add an `EventListener` to a `<div>` so that I can drop a file to it for reading a csv file. Below is my simple HTML code that adds an `EventListener`, but when I dragged and dropped a file, the Chrome browser keeps downloading the file that I dropped and the console output "hey" is not printed. If anyone could let me know what is wrong I'd greatly appreciate the help. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
<style>
#drop{
  border:2px dashed #bbb;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:25px;
  text-align:center;
  width:128px;
  font:20pt bold,"Vollkorn";color:#bbb
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="drop">Drop a file here</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var drop_dom_element = document.getElementById('drop');
        var workbook;

        /* set up drag-and-drop event */
        function handleDrop(e) {
          console.log('hello');
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log('hey');
        }

        drop_dom_element.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
        console.log('Done');        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default behaviour of most (all?) elements is not to allow dropping. Read [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations#droptargets).

> A listener for the dragenter and dragover events are used to indicate
>   valid drop targets, that is, places where dragged items may be
>   dropped. Most areas of a web page or application are not valid places
>   to drop data. Thus, the default handling of these events is not to
>   allow a drop.

Adding `event.preventDefault()` to the `dragover` event seems to do the trick in current versions of Firefox and Chrome.

```
element.addEventListener("dragover", function( event ) {
  // prevent default to allow drop
  event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Under [Performing a Drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations#drop):

> When the user releases the mouse, the drag and drop operation ends. If
>   the mouse was released over an element that is a valid drop target,
>   that is, one that cancelled the last dragenter or dragover event, and
>   then the drop will be successful, and a drop event will fire at the
>   target. Otherwise, the drag operation is cancelled, and no drop event
>   is fired.

---

The reason for adding the `preventDefault` call to the `drop` event function too is to prevent the default behaviour browsers might have such as immediately opening links and images.

You can see in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k2zw64yx/) that dragging text or images will trigger the `drop` event, but Firefox and Chrome will also open images and links.

Comment: Thank you. Seems like adding this `dragover` listener solved the issue. But, could you please explain me why `dragover` is needed in addition to just `drop`? It wasn't clear to me from reading the MDN reference you shared. Thank you!

Comment: thank you so much for providing more info! Based on the documentation you provided, I have a few follow-up questions: 1) Seems like the `document.preventDefault()` for `dragover` is to prevent the default handling of draggable objects by the browser? In that case, why don't we cancel (`preventDefault()`) on the `<div>` element instead of the whole `document`? My understanding is that if we `preventDefault` on `document`, it will indicate that the `document` is droppable 2) Why don't we also need to do `preventDefault` for `dragenter`? Is that strictly either `dragover` OR `dragenter`?

Comment: @user1330974 1. By all means, add the event handler to a specific element, and not the entire document, I was just careless when copy pasting. Just as you can add a `click` event to the document, you can do with others. Keep in mind that the `dragover` event is triggered just like mouseover (even if it's said to occur every few hundred ms, it is far more frequent on my version of Chrome).

Comment: @user1330974 2. For this purpose, `dragover` and `dragenter` are normally mentioned in pair; preventing default for both is suggested. However, `dragenter` on its own does nothing in my Firefox and Chrome, while `dragover` seems to be sufficient. Unfortunately, I haven't found any more information on it. You should probably include both just to be on the safe side.